# Highlight current line, but not for files inside certain dirs

Tags: highlight, working-directory

I'd like to be able to highlight the current line the cursor is at, but not for files from certain directories. That's because I noticed the rendering becomes slow if I highlight the lines within a Rails project - probably because I use rails.vim and its slowing down things.

So, is there a way to highlight current line, but not when I'm in, say, `~/Work/my_rails_project_1` or `~/Work/my_rails_project_2`?

Answer (score 3):

I assume by "Highlight current line" that you're referring to the `set cursorline` option?

Sounds like a job for autocmd's

I'd do something like:

```
autocmd BufEnter * call UnhighlightLine()

function! UnhighlightLine()
   if (expand('%:p') =~ '/Work/my_rails_project_1\|/Work/my_rails_project_2')
      set nocursorline
   else
      set cursorline
   endif
endfunction
```

`autocmd BufEnter *` will trigger when you enter a new file

`expand('%:p')` Gives the current files path.

I have two paths separated by `\|` meaning it can match either one. If you want more paths just continue to separate with `\|`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say this has worked. It highlights cursorline in all files now, including the ones in the said dirs.

Comment: There could be a few things going on. You might try surrounding the `expand()` function in an `fnameescape()` function. This just makes sure things are properly formatted for a directory. For more specific help, it might help to see the output of `:echo expand('%:p')` on your system. This will make sure we're crafting the regular expression correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for autocmds. This works for me:

```vim
" set by default
set cursorline
" unset for specific cases  
autocmd BufEnter ~/Work/my_rails_project_1/*,~/Work/my_rails_project_2/* setlocal nocursorline
```

The `*`matches path separators, so this will apply to all directories inside `~/Work/my_rails_project_1/` and 
`~/Work/my_rails_project_2/`. The `setlocal` will restrict the change to matching buffers.